# PHP Conditional Syntax: function == result or function

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements, syntactic-sugar

I recently came across this in a PHP script:

```
fseek($gi->filehandle, $gi->record_length, SEEK_SET) == 0 or die("fseek failed");
```

What I'm wondering, is if this is somehow better than what I would consider to be a more traditional syntax:

```
$seek = fseek($gi->filehandle, $gi->record_length, SEEK_SET);
if ($seek !==0) {
    die("fseek failed");
}
```

The first method avoids assigning the results of fseek to a variable, but does that really matter? Does the first method do a better job keeping things out of memory? (Not that that would matter for a function that returns a small integer.)

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are no difference in these.

Except that:

- in first code sample you better use `=== 0` not `== 0`
- in second code sample you create one small and useless variable, but I guess it doesn't do any harm.

You can also write like this if you prefer:

```
if (fseek($gi->filehandle, $gi->record_length, SEEK_SET) !== 0) {
    die("fseek failed");
}
```

Most important is consistency in your code. If you use `if`s in such cases in your code, then use `if`s always. If you like short syntax, then use it always when it's possible. Don't make mix of both or your code will become less readable.